# Where is the HM "Rock Smash" in Pokemon Omega Ruby/Alpha Sapphire (oras)?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I've been running around Mauville, Verdandorf and Slateport for a long time and I still can't find rock smash. I'm at the point where there is a girl standing in a cave in front of rocks and says you need rock smadh to pass. I have 3 badges already. PLEASE HELP! 0_0

Comment: There's an answer in the linked question now.

Answer (score 0):

After you defeat Wally in front of Watson's gym, he gives it to you. :)